# Implement CERT rules using MPS

Tags: dsl, mps

I am trying to develop a DSL for CERT Java Coding guidelines. That time I got a framework called jetbrains MPS.I tried most of the documents available in jetbrains site. But those are not sufficient for my work. Two doubts are can I implement CERT Java Coding guidelines using MPS and anybody knows any previous work and good documents related to this.

Answer (score 0):

I have no isights what CERT is, but we do use MPS heavily and put much effort in enabling other to do the same. We work on a open source C implementation inside of MPS called [mbeddr](http://mbeddr.com). Beside the fact that it is a C implementation we also open source our extension to MPS that are generally useful out of C. The blog also contains some insights about how to build languages in MPS and there is a paper section where you can find information about various aspects of build languages (with MPS). There are also ways to get in touch with us.